# Derivability of a function with an infinity of zeroes

Tags: functions, derivatives, vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a normed vector space and $a\in F$. Is there a non zero function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow F$,  such that $f'(a)=0$ and $f$ is $0$ an infinity of times in any neighborhood of $a$ ?

If not, how can one prove it isn't possible ?

PS : This isn't homework , I was just wondering because if it were to be impossible, it would make a proof I'm working on easier.

Comment: Well, first: the vector space $\;F\;$ must be such that limits, derivatives and stuff can be defined there. Assuming this, you can always take $\;f=0\;$ .

Comment: As per @Timbuc's comment, you should add that $f$ should be not be $=0$ on any neighborhood of $a$. While we're at it, you could also mention the topology used on $F$...

Comment: @AlexH. I was just away :) I'll accept it, it's exactly was I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems perfectly possible to me.

Take $F = \mathbb R$, $a=0$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ (with $f(0)=0)$.

If I'm not mistaken, $f$ even verifies $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Made it clearer

Comment: Ok now, but then: is $\;f(x)=0\;$ an infinity of times in *any* neighborhood of zero? By this I understand the OP meant whether $\;f\;$ has infinite zeros in any neighborhood of zero.

Comment: Isn't it the case that $f$ is nil on $\{ \frac{1}{2k\pi} \}_k$ which intersects any neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Of course: I completely oversaw that part of the definition of $\;f\;$ when writing the above. Thank you. +1

Comment: Made the formatting clearer